# Label's color changes when you are typing in the login field?

Tags: html, css, authentication, input

I want to make the same login effect than Twitter.

On twitter.com/login, you see that when you are typing in the text area, the grey color of the label "Phone, email, or username" or "Password" changes to blue.

So I've tried to make `input:focus label {color: blue;}`

But it doesn't work, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

try using the general sibling selector like this

```
input:focus ~ label{
  color: #0000ff;
}
```

Note that this code assumes `input` and `label` are siblings

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because what you wrote basically says: "if I focus my input, put this css on my label which is a child of input". Now I'm assuming since this wouldn't be valid html, your label is not a child of your input.

The answer @arnavpanwar99 provided is correct, usually your input and label are siblings like this:

```
<div>
  <label>My Label</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

unfortunately, the sibling selector only works from left to right, meaning that something like this: `input:focus ~ label` would once again not work, since it goes once again from left to right (and the label is on the left side of your input, therefore the code is not affecting it).

Now if we switch positions, it would work:

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

label {
  color: grey;
}

input:focus ~ label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" />
<label>My Label</label>
</div>
```

But unfortunately, now the label is on the wrong side.

The trick is, to use css (in my case I just used float: left but you can basically do everything you want to make it look right) to fix the appearance, while still using the "wrong" html setup:

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

label {
  color: grey;
}

input:focus ~ label {
  color: red;
}

.pullLeft {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" />
<label class="pullLeft">My Label</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a class on a surrounding div and use :focus-within on that div followed by label to change the color of the label.

The reason why this works is because instead of looking for child elements of input, it checks if something is being focused within the surrounding div.

```css
    .input-group:focus-within label {       
        color: red;    
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <label>My Label</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

You can read more about focus-within here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within